# Djangop Heroku, when sending an e-mail, we get an error 500, how to fix?

Tags: django, heroku

When I sent letters from the local server, everything worked, uploading the project on heroku, when sending a letter to the mail we get this error Server Error (500) how to fix ??

**form**

```
<form action="{% url 'app:get_ticket' session.id place.id price_total %}" method="get" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" name="email_input" class= "input-email" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="E-mail" required>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">{% trans 'Забронювати' %}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**form handler for send mail**

```
        subject = name_cinema
        html_message = render_to_string('app_template/mail_template.html', context)
        plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
        from_email = 'From <cinemacount12090@gmail.com>'
        to = email

        mail.send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [to], html_message=html_message)
```

**setings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'examplepass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

in the logs, I see no more errors, only here the status is 500 when sending an email

```
2020-06-16T21:43:42.774577+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/js/urlify.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=ecc368c1-4ee3-415d-8b22-497b89832341 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=9287 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:42.775073+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:42 +0300] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:42.778538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=2b33faa1-2939-4493-8af3-939d8ceee19a fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=62821 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:42.998858+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:42 +0300] "GET /static/admin/img/search.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:42.998941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/img/search.svg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=20a3dfb9-bfd4-41ff-80d3-9542e99cbe9c fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=776 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:43.119783+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:43 +0300] "GET /static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/base.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:43.119911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=7f6810fd-4df2-4981-a74a-10b3948e730c fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=649 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.007370+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:45 +0300] "GET /admin/app/session/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8582 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:45.007989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/app/session/add/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=74b922d9-9422-421f-af0b-d65ad7a57f21 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=77ms status=200 bytes=9132 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.298308+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:45 +0300] "GET /static/admin/css/forms.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:45.298468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/forms.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=cf8e0dbb-f10b-45f9-aa11-9e5507481dcf fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=8850 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.299188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/js/calendar.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=80d5ec77-30dc-44f0-8b34-4fa3b03e4334 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=8123 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.305429+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:45 +0300] "GET /static/admin/js/calendar.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:45.309773+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:45 +0300] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:45.310569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/jsi18n/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=9ad86814-f007-4bc9-b6c2-5b5a019d1a3e fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=3502 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.719761+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:45 +0300] "GET /static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:45.721400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=d6f8481b-1682-4cef-86ab-e33cf296dc52 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=20579 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.735035+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/css/widgets.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=70d337e7-c791-4de5-8cd8-46a6a22ffd3d fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=10655 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:45.740971+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:45 +0300] "GET /static/admin/css/widgets.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:46.145337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/js/change_form.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=2ced0aa2-e44e-4c80-967d-717b491f79e6 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1056 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:46.149868+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:46 +0300] "GET /static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:46.150622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/js/prepopulate_init.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=6162dbb2-4c64-4208-87d1-fde63b1b5434 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=839 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:46.151640+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:46 +0300] "GET /static/admin/js/change_form.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:46.422399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/img/icon-calendar.svg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=10c4900c-1a3b-48d8-90dd-8275d942cdc4 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1405 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:46.428558+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:46 +0300] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-calendar.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/widgets.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:54.366466+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/admin/app/session/add/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=c074f5df-f548-4beb-b650-c9f679735753 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=50ms status=302 bytes=764 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:54.371695+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:54 +0300] "POST /admin/app/session/add/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:54.601224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/app/session/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=307ad402-1b75-46f2-bfe0-9dd124890fa8 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=116ms status=200 bytes=10650 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:54.606859+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:54 +0300] "GET /admin/app/session/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10016 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/add/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:54.791053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/jsi18n/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=89534479-01ce-45f5-9640-72976521d9e2 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=3502 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:54.797145+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:54 +0300] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:54.990687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=540e958a-7ea6-4086-8113-b7ba931aa0af fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=754 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:54.996755+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:54 +0300] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/base.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:57.977815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=8a1fd32f-cc94-4418-a691-a1234c761e2c fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=225 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:57.984102+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:57 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.204277+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=a73764b0-5205-4625-9a30-421f52d3d551 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=78ms status=200 bytes=34054 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:58.209347+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 33632 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/admin/app/session/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.526104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/posters/1zqd94pkdvoinick_BGZgXLO.jpg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=ab2783a9-1529-4706-9034-b7ddc29cc50f fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=433 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:58.532467+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /media/posters/1zqd94pkdvoinick_BGZgXLO.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.535877+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /media/posters/asd_IOwdjsH.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.536450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/posters/asd_IOwdjsH.jpg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=4a767138-4a95-49f2-a1e9-da7e8838afd1 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=433 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:58.538864+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /media/posters/dsa.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.538963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/posters/dsa.jpg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=2ce46125-cdec-488a-b948-66c5709f9df0 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=433 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:58.783759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/posters/898053.jpg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=9151b45a-8854-4594-b18c-5e67f23f7429 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=433 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:58.786752+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /media/posters/Taras._Povernennia_2019_UKR_poster_No.2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.787408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/posters/Taras._Povernennia_2019_UKR_poster_No.2.jpg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=f3638992-b330-416b-81dd-4408711d5366 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=433 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:43:58.789817+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /media/posters/898053.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.790322+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:43:58 +0300] "GET /media/posters/b21d0ecf7dfc.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:43:58.790500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/posters/b21d0ecf7dfc.jpg" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=7ff535fb-147c-48e7-981b-13b0a6204204 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=433 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.201613+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /en/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51889 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.204149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/sessions/" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=7c4f293e-e459-49b4-98a6-b51120687cb9 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=99ms status=200 bytes=52311 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.469889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/normalize.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=0c8f2479-3638-48e0-b36a-f33ac261d18b fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=201 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.473800+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.474174+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/css/fontawsome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.474390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=c1f59ed4-ad7b-41ea-86ea-d9f2e74297fc fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=202 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.474418+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=3450fa1f-f231-48c3-8d52-e83ea9f8077c fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=201 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.474484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/fontawsome.min.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=7043a704-dce0-4748-bdb6-d41de077f08f fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=201 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.474999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/base.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=77565c85-9a1f-4e7f-baf9-62662f710ff1 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=201 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.475962+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.82.109 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.476645+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.38.83.15 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.477555+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=fbcc8701-5cb1-4fd2-9e35-46e0b203f286 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=202 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.478085+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.65.206 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.479703+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.230.5 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.554188+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 416 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.554861+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=96bfa1fb-021a-48c9-8b4f-6de4ba7775e5 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=416 bytes=225 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.558975+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.561476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=90594b2d-9816-475f-a591-2a66d126d4da fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=200 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:14.638307+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.97.20.110 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:14 +0300] "GET /static/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:14.641879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=739f8417-c674-4b75-b0f4-eef490d6144d fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=68601 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:16.864888+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:16 +0300] "GET /en/reserve/16/5/47 HTTP/1.1" 200 1277685 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/sessions/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:16.881989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/reserve/16/5/47" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=193ead33-9569-486a-90b5-ba85a05dcb7e fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1068ms status=200 bytes=1278109 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:17.433961+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/hall.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=2a8c1722-7591-4c48-a44c-bd62da7970ea fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1510 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:17.439498+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.10.230.5 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:17 +0300] "GET /static/css/hall.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/reserve/16/5/47" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:19.478119+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:19 +0300] "GET /en/reservation_ticket/5/47/2/16556/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 19760 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/reserve/16/5/47" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:19.478410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/reservation_ticket/5/47/2/16556/1" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=b552d290-02c5-44fc-866b-fa3ebcdc435c fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=20182 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:19.647843+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:19 +0300] "GET /static/css/reservations.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/reservation_ticket/5/47/2/16556/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:19.648113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/reservations.css" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=77dba4b0-1761-49d5-b668-3cf43d3d671b fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=4554 protocol=https
2020-06-16T21:44:22.893805+00:00 app[web.1]: [3, 22, 39, 80, 89, 73, 16, 98, 15, 76, 13, 4, 45]
2020-06-16T21:44:22.893891+00:00 app[web.1]: 322398089731698157613445
2020-06-16T21:44:22.987166+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.34.14.131 - - [17/Jun/2020:00:44:22 +0300] "GET /en/get_ticket/47/16556/73/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=SF8mqeob1C37XlMvoUiGhHgeLALen8tQtDnmsBPIZYxu1jQy3PB0YWZI6sXeXqdy&email_input=reabko15%40gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com/en/reservation_ticket/5/47/2/16556/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
2020-06-16T21:44:22.987479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/get_ticket/47/16556/73/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=SF8mqeob1C37XlMvoUiGhHgeLALen8tQtDnmsBPIZYxu1jQy3PB0YWZI6sXeXqdy&email_input=reabko15%40gmail.com" host=cinemaxpro.herokuapp.com request_id=f2f1a4a8-92ad-47be-809b-57c668dddc17 fwd="176.120.63.218" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=108ms status=500 bytes=402 protocol=https
```

Comment: Code 500 is a server error. Try to find the server logs which will tell you more about the cause. You may need to enable them first. Furthermore, share the code for sending the email(the handler of the form you posted).

Comment: added a handler in the question, but in the logs I do not observe errors, only the status is 500 when sending an email

Comment: I do not see errors in the handler. You need to find a way to enable more logging. Look for specific information on how to enable error logs for django/heroku setup. Otherwise it is just a guessing game, especially when it comes to email.

Comment: Please share your relevant mail settings (make sure to leave passwords etc. out).

Comment: @Chris, Added, help me, please, otherwise I do not know what to look for

Comment: Gmail isn't a good tool for programmatic email delivery. Have you enabled "less secure app support"? (I still recommend using something built for this instead like Mailgun or SendGrid.) It's hard to know what's going wrong without logs. Are you _entirely sure_ that there isn't more information there? Normally you'd get a bunch of output.

Comment: @Chris, added most of the logs, but there I see nothing suspicious

Comment: @Chris, "less secure app support"? yes

Comment: @Chris How to connect sendgrid in Django? Are there any articles on the subject about connecting to the sendgrid Django?

Comment: [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), and yes, [there are plenty of articles about using SendGrid with Django](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sendgrid+django). Please remember to search these types of things. You're expected to do some of this on your own.